# Jquery content slider prev next

Tags: jquery, slideshow, carousel

I need some help with the following matter. I have this

http://jsfiddle.net/WGkPV/1/

I would like to have 3 div's show and when i press next the next div will show. (same for previous)
With a nice sliding effect. Thanks

```
<div class="mydivs">
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>div 2</div>
    <div>div 3</div>
    <div>div 4</div>
    <div>div 5</div>
    <div>div 6</div>
    <div>div 7</div>
    <div>div 8</div>
</div>
<button name="prev">go to previous div</button>
<button name="next">go to next div</button>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('.mydivs>div');
    var now = 0; // currently shown div
    var first3 = $('.mydivs > div:lt(3)');
    var first = $('.mydivs > div:lt(1)');
    divs.hide();
    first3.show();
    $("button[name=next]").click(function (e) {

        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now > 0) ? now + 1 : divs.length + 1;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // or .css('display','block');
        //console.log(divs.length, now);
    });
    $("button[name=prev]").click(function (e) {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // or .css('display','block');
        //console.log(divs.length, now);
    });
});

.mydivs {
    height:300px;
    border:5px solid #ccf;
    width:600px;
}
.mydivs>div {
    height:100%;
    width:195px;
    background-color:red;
    overflow-y:auto;
    border:5px solid #ff0;
    padding:1em;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? have you tried any plugins? do you want to do all the code yourself?

Comment: You can google for 'carousel', which seems to be what you're after. But you're not going to get a solution at Stack Overflow without a more elaborate question description (including a description of your own efforts). Google is your friend :)

Comment: was editing the question